# Remove a column in dataframe if a particular value meets a condition in R

Tags: r, data-science, data-wrangling

After a lot of research, I'm struggling to do what should be straightforward in R. I am trying to delete columns only (not rows) if a value from a *particular* row and *particular* column meets a condition. For example I have a dataframe:

```
V1 <- c(1:2)
V2 <- c(2:3)
df1 <- data.frame(V1, V2)
```

| V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

I want to delete the entire column V2 if Row2/V2 is less than 4. As you can see in this example, the value in question is 3.

In which case I would be left with a dataframe that is equivalent to:

```
V1 <- c(1:2)
df1 <- data.frame(V1)
```

| V1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want an `if` clause.

```
df1 <- if (df1[nrow(df1), 2] < 4) {
  df1[, -2, drop=FALSE]
} else {
  df1
}
df1
#   V1
# 1  1
# 2  2
```

Using column names:

```
n <- 'V2'
df1 <- if (df1[nrow(df1), n] < 4) {
  df1[, setdiff(names(df1), n), drop=FALSE]
} else {
  df1
}
df1
#   V1
# 1  1
# 2  2
```

Comment: Thanks for this, any way I could use this in code that is being used with datasets that get updated, increasing in size, but the value in question will always be in the last row?

Comment: @willbrown Yes sure, use `nrow`, see update.

Comment: Spot on , thanks very much for this! You've solved a day long headache and meant I have a better chance of sleeping tonight.

Comment: Sorry, another one. Can this be done with column names rather than indexes? If I use this method multiple times (for different values) the column indexes will shift. When I try to use column names I get "Error in... invalid argument to unary operator"

Comment: @willbrown You could use `setdiff` in such cases, see update. Another way would be to translate names into indeces using `which(names(df1) == 'V2')`, but I think `setdiff` is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Without an `if` clause, you can do:

```r
df1[seq_along(df1)[ifelse(df1$V2[2] < 4, -2, -(length(df1) + 1))]]
#>   V1
#> 1  1
#> 2  2
```